# My Galaxy S has had a software upgrade and now it only types digits on the 3 x 4 keypad

Tags: keyboard

I have tried a factory reset and messed with all the settings, no luck. I even tried an external keypad app. It just keeps texting numbers when I use the samsung 3 x 4 keypad even when its on the ABC setting. Please help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Go into:

- Settings
- Language & Keyboard Settings
- Samsung Keyboard
- Keypad types, tap that

There is various styles , *3x4 keypad* is probably selected, the one you need is ***Qwerty Keyboard***.

Comment: Hail the Qwerty :)